# Assign Firebase snapshot to a variable

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save info that I am reading from my Firebase Database into a variable.  This is the way I am reading my info:

```
dbHandle = dbReference?.child("users").child(userEmail!).child("state").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let userState = (snapshot.value as? String){
            var taxRate = self.stateAbbreviations[userState]!
            print(taxRate)
        }

    })
```

My question is now how do I make userState & taxRate visible outside of this call?

I have tried declaring userState outside of the call, initializing it within, and referencing it outside again but it doesn't work.  For example:

```
var userState:String? = ""
dbHandle = dbReference?.child("users").child(userEmail!).child("state").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let userState = (snapshot.value as? String)
        var taxRate = self.stateAbbreviations[userState]!
        print(taxRate)
    })
print(userState)
```

But it only prints out ""

Any advice??

Comment: The userState you are declaring within the closure is not the same one.  You would need to reference it as `self.userState =`

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a `var userState` as an empty string and your print outside the completion retrieve its default value, in your firebase completion you are initializing another userState variable with `let userState =`

If you want to use userState and taxRate outside the call you can do it in this way, for example:

```
// Create your variables 
var userState: String = “”

//Create a func with completion handler
func getUserStateAndTaxRate(completion:((String,String) -> Void)?) {
    dbHandle = dbReference?.child("users").child(userEmail!).child("state").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let userState = (snapshot.value as? String)
        var taxRate = self.stateAbbreviations[userState]!
        print(taxRate)
        completion?(userState, taxRate)
    })
}

//Then call it
getUserStateAndTaxRate { (userState, taxRate) in 
    // userState and taxRate are now available 
    self.userState = userState 
    self.taxRate = taxRate 
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your advice.  Unfortunately, this does not work either.  After I call getUserStateAndTaxRate, userState and taxRate are still empty.  Also, just for debugging purposes i tried putting a print statement right before "self.userState = userState", but it is never printed, so I'm wondering if that code is even being executed

Comment: Hi! Just to be sure have you tried to print your snapshot.value?

Comment: within the getUserStateAndTaxRate function?

Comment: actually, that won't print either.  Nothing I put inside the code block after the dbHandle line gets printed.  Like if I do print(userState) right after I capture the snapshot

Comment: Check your db query because if you are not receiving the snapshot response that is the problem ;) My code is just an example to explain how you can manage the response of an asynchronous query.